# Adding Spartacus - Package has unmet peer dependencies

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I just created a brand new project using the newest angular CLI 13.3.6 (node 16.15.0, yarn 1.22.15). I'm trying to add spartacus as described here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries-4-x/ but when I run

```
ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest
```

I get the following error:

> ‼ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
> No terminal detected. '--skip-confirmation' can be used to bypass installation confirmation. Ensure package name is correct prior to '--skip-confirmation' option usage.
> Command aborted.

I also tried --force as suggested by @AhmedSHA256 - no use. That's what I get:

> ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest --skip-confirmation --force
>
> - Determining package manager...
>   i Using package manager: npm
> - Loading package information from registry...
>   ‼ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
> - Installing package...
>   npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
>   npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! While resolving: spartacus@0.0.0
>   npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.3.9
>   npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
>   npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~13.3.0" from the root project
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>   npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"^12.0.5" from @spartacus/schematics@4.3.3
>   npm ERR! node_modules/@spartacus/schematics
>   npm ERR!   dev @spartacus/schematics@"4.3.3" from the root project
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
>   npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
>   npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! See C:\Users\kpw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\kpw\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-20T09_54_05_770Z-debug-0.log
> × Package install failed, see above.

What can I do to add spartacus?

Comment: Btw I already tried adding the '--skip-confirmation' - it doesn't help

Comment: --force always works

Comment: I edited my question and pasted what I get when I use --force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Spartacus v4 supports only Angular v12

At the time of writing, the latest version of Spartacus (v4) supports only Angular 12. You have installed Angular 13 and that's probably why you're getting warnings about incompatible peer dependencies. For more, see the [requirements docs of Spartacus v4](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries-4-x/#front-end-development-requirements).

Please create a fresh Angular 12 application, and then install Spartacus v4.

Note: The future major release of Spartacus (v5) plans to support a new major version of Angular.

#### How to install Spartacus (and Angular) in specific versions

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72375890/11734692

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, that worked after adding the '--skip-confirmation' flag at the end of the  'ng add' command