# How to install Spartacus (and Angular) in a specific version

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

**How can I create an Angular app in specific version (e.g. v12)? And then how to install Spartacus in specific version (e.g. v4)?**

The [docs of Spartacus](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/) describe only how to install the latest version of Spartacus:  `ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest`

And the [docs of Angular](https://angular.io/cli/new) describe only how to create a fresh Angular app using the currently installed (latest?) version of Angular: `ng new app-name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How to create Angular app in specific version

If you want to create a fresh Angular app in specific Angular version (e.g. v12), please run:

```
npx @angular/cli@12 new app-name
```

#### How to install Spartacus in specific version

If you want to install Spartacus in specific version (e.g. v4), please run:

```
ng add @spartacus/schematics@4
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after following both the steps. -
> ng "add" "@spartacus/schematics@4"

i Using package manager: npm
‼ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.


Please note that for most Spartacus features to be properly configured, the Account feature is required. Assisted Services Module, Import/Export, Saved Cart, Quick Order, Checkout, Order, Product -
...r,  - Personalization, User - Account, User - Profile
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Tools\workspace\app-name\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs