# Unable to add spartacus to Angular

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I followed official documentation and link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375889/how-to-install-spartacus-and-angular-in-a-specific-version/72375890) but none of it helped me to get going.
I keep getting the below error -

```
C:\Tools\workspace\app-name>npm run ng add @spartacus/schematics@4

> app-name@0.0.0 ng C:\Tools\workspace\app-name
> ng "add" "@spartacus/schematics@4"

i Using package manager: npm
‼ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.

The package @spartacus/schematics@4 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
√ Packages successfully installed.
? Which Spartacus features would you like to set up?
Please note that for most Spartacus features to be properly configured, the Account feature is required. Assisted Services Module, Import/Export, Saved Cart, Quick Order, Checkout, Order, Product -
Variants, Product - Image Zoom, SmartEdit, Store Finder, Tracking - Personalization, User - Account, User - Profile
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Tools\workspace\app-name\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-name@0.0.0 ng: `ng "add" "@spartacus/schematics@4"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app-name@0.0.0 ng script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M1088751\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-01T08_35_23_119Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It's just a shot in the dark, but I followed the "Must use import to load ES Module" error and I got this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported/69491823#69491823

Comment: @Mihai thanks but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to use Angular 12 with Spartacus v4. See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries-4-x/

Answer (score 0):

Check your angular version by running the below command in your command prompt

```
ng version
```

As per Spartacus documentation https://github.com/SAP/spartacus#requirements

**Install Angular 12 version by running**

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm i @angular/cli@12.2.18`

**Install Node 14.** version**
If you may find how to use nodejs specific version in local folder

This will resolve your issue